# Batch script to get the time of file when it arrived at given location

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

i have a automated JOB that will look inside a folder for some specific file.I need to create a Batch Script that will look inside that folder and search those files which arrived at a certain time. If files are there in the folder which arrived at that point of time then it will move those files at different location.

Thanks 
Prakhar

Comment: What OS? what batch/job control system? This will be totally different under a POSIX system vs. mainframe JES or something. Are the files "arriving" being newly-created on your host (e.g. from a network job) or moved locally within the filesystem?

Comment: @BRPocock I am using windows 7 and those files will come from a source  location to a Target folder, so the script will look in the target folder and get the time of their arrival. if the time of arrival is e.g. say 10:00:00(assuming 24 hour's format), then it will move those files to some different location.

Answer (score 0):

Rather you need [SCHTASKS](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html)  :

```
SCHTASKS /create /tn "move files" /tr "cmd /c move /y \"c:\file1\" \"c:\other_dir\file1"" /sc daily /sd 01/01/2015 /st 10:00
```

you can export the command to a separate bat and schedule its call"

```
SCHTASKS /create /tn "move files" /tr "cmd /c c:\dir\some.bat" /sc daily /sd 01/01/2015 /st 10:00
```

Where the some.bat content is like:

```
@echo off
move /y "c:\dir1\file1" "c:\other_dir\file1"
```

Comment: Great , but i am having  a scheduling tool that will perform this task without  SCHTASKS.
Is there any other way to do the same.

Comment: @PRAX - you can use your scheduling tool to call the command.But SCHTASKS is built-in the windows and this is the only way for me to give a  "portable" example.